# Check input value length

Tags: javascript, validation, input

I have a problem with input checking. I don't want to send the request if the input length is less than 3.

My form:

```
<form method='post' action=''>
    Albūma nosaukums: # # this is the input --><input id='titleeee' type='text' name'album_title' /><br />

    Bilde Nr 1: <input type='file' name='pic_nr1' /><br />
    Bilde Nr 2: <input type='file' name='pic_nr2' /><br />
    Bilde Nr 3: <input type='file' name='pic_nr2' /><br />

    Aktīvs*: 
    <select>
        <option>Jā</option>
        <option>Nē</option>
    </select>

    <br />

    <input Onclick='testlenght(document.getElementById("titleeee"), "Tavs albūma nosaukums ir pa īsu!", "3")' type='submit' value='Pievienot' />
</form>
```

Comment: You've referenced `testlenght()`, but where is the function?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You can add a form onsubmit handler, something like:

```
<form onsubmit="return validate();">

</form>


<script>function validate() {
 // check if input is bigger than 3
 var value = document.getElementById('titleeee').value;
 if (value.length < 3) {
   return false; // keep form from submitting
 }

 // else form is good let it submit, of course you will 
 // probably want to alert the user WHAT went wrong.

 return true;
}</script>
```

Comment: Can you please type full skript, i am not smart in javascript ;(

Comment: that should be the full thing

Comment: I know this post is years old, but to help some beginners (Beginners should have a chance too, since we all began in similar ways.. sooo..) : The part of `<form...` to `</form>` should go in your plain html document and that whole `function` part into a `<script> (put it here) </script>` tag in that same document, *or* put it in a separate file called `script.js` and reference it with `<script src='script.js'></script>`. That's all. Sorry, if this comment isn't "S.O. compilant", I just want to help some bloody beginners.

Comment: I think the "return" statement is missing: <form onsubmit="return validate();">

Answer (score 6):

`<input type='text' minlength=3 /><br />`

if browser supports html5,

it will automatical be validate attributes(minlength) in tag

but Safari(iOS) doesn't working

Answer (score 0):

There's 3 way's I would do this.

**1:**

```
const Element = document.getElementById("Element-ID");
if (Element.value.length >= 3) {
    // Do your code thing!
    console.log("Input length is longer or is 3");
};
```

**2:**

```
<input type="text" minlength=3/>
// I recommend option 1 sense it's more customize able.
```

**3:**

```
const Element = ddocument.getElementById("Element-ID");

switch(Element.value.length) {
    case 3:
    console.log("length is 3");
    break;
    
    default:
    console.log("length is not 3 or is less then 3");
    break;
};
```