# How check input maxlength < 1GB?

Tags: javascript

I have 1 TextBox input data in PHP.

I want check limit input.

How check input maxlength < 1GB?

Comment: I am not sure, but can you check the file size in a plain text document, count the number of letter, and check the number of text instead?

Comment: I'm not sure many browsers are going to be able to process 1GB of text in javascript

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to know the byte size of the input?

Regardless, to calculate the byte size of a string in Javascript you can use:

```
function stringSize(s) {
    return encodeURI(s).split(/%..|./).length - 1;
}
```

This assumes that you're using UTF-8. Not sure if this would work with other encodings.

Comment: This problem is check 1GB data.

Comment: @DT: I'm not sure what you're asking. What is this "data" you speak of, and where are you measuring it? How much data is transferred across the wire, storage space or what?

Comment: check input maxlength < 1GB by Javascript when input text into TextBox.

Answer (score 0):

This can be counting the lines of characters ..The code will be

```
 var value = document.getElementById('titleeee').value;


if (value.length < 3) { //replace with your character length


//the rest of ur code



}
```

Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12164751/check-input-value-length) for more info

Comment: One character != 1 byte. For example, å is 2 bytes. Other characters are bigger still.

Comment: String t="名称未設定-1.indd": Byte <> Length

Answer (score -1):

1GB = 1024mb = 1048576kb = 1073741824 characters

Comment: Characters in JavaScript aren't necessarily stored as 1 byte, especially if we're talking about Unicode characters.

Comment: @Joshpbarron: I believe the answerer is assuming binary gigabytes, in which case 1GiB = 1073741824B.

Comment: I thought so to, however the answer's units were incorrect. This just showed how easy it is to make the mistake.

Comment: 1Gb equals 1024 in Base 2 definition. On the other hand you are rigth here the Base 10 definition needs to be used.

Comment: String t="名称未設定-1.indd": Byte <> Length