# I need to check lenght of password but for some reason .lenght doesnt work?

Tags: javascript

- If i do `password1.lenghth` in `if()` and test the lenght it still
  displays that passwords are shorter than 5.
- I'm still in school so we are doing simple stuff that might seem
  obvious but are not to me.
- Also tried putting `var pass_lenght= password1.lenght;` and `var
  pass_lenght=  document.getElementById("password1").lenght;` didn't
  work Anyone knows why?

Thanks

```
    var password1= document.getElementById("password1");
    var password2= document.getElementById("password2");
    password1.addEventListener("blur",function()
    {

        if (password1!= password2) {     
            password1.setAttribute("class","wrong");
            password2.setAttribute("class","wrong");
            return false;
            } 

            else if(password1.lenght<5)
            {
            password1.setAttribute("class","wrong");
            return false;

            }
            else
            {
            password1.setAttribute("class","correct");
            }
    });




    password1.addEventListener("blur",function()
    {

        if (password1!= lozinka2) {     
            password1.setAttribute("class","wrong");
            password2.setAttribute("class","wrong");
            return false;
            } 

            else if(password2.lenght<5)
            {
            password2.setAttribute("class","wrong");
            return false;
            }
            else
                {
            password2.setAttribute("class","correct");
        }
    });
```

Comment: You can't measure the length of an element, but you need either the length of its value (if it's an input element) or its content. And you need to spell it right.

Comment: welcome to Stack Overflow. it's value.length as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12164751/check-input-value-length/12164778 btw

Comment: It's input for a password yes. So do I put element in its own variable and then get it's lenght?

Comment: by the way, it's length, not lenght

Comment: corrected that thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some flaws in the above code which are as follows:

1. If you want the actual text you should use the `value` attribute.

```
var password1= document.getElementById("password1").value;
```

2. It might be because your spelling of `length` is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

What seems to be the problem is that you are not actually accessing the length. Your `getElementById` does exactly what it says, get an **element** by id. But you want the value entered, not the element.

```
You: password1.length
Correct: password1.value.length
```

Also, even if you change that, the `else if` statement wouldn't even be reached, so that would be pointless.

So, *only change* the `password1` and `password2` variables to:

```
var password1= document.getElementById("password1").value;
var password2= document.getElementById("password2").value;
```

Comment: the thing is if i change password1  to have  .values i get error in console 
" TypeError: password1 .addEventListener is not a function:validacija.js:267:11"

Answer (score 0):

You normally measure the length of an input field but you can never measure the length directly off an element. You will have to get the value of input field by:

```
var password1= document.getElementById("password1").value;

console.log(password1.length) //======> this will print the length.
```